# why can't I load packages to R-studios

Tags: r

> install.packages("NUTS2.xlsx")
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘NUTS2.xlsx’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

help anyone?

Comment: The package doesn't exist. Why do you think there is such a package?

Comment: Are you trying to read in a _file_ called NUTS2.xlsx?